# $map query returning Boolean value instead of data in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have data:

```
{
        "_id": "63b6c24fa14b7a7762f053f5",
        "question": [
            {
                "type": "single",
                "optional": false,
                "options": null,
                "is_disable": false,
                "is_deleted": true,
                "draggable": false,
                "choice": null,
                "updated_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
                "deleted_by": null,
                "_id": "63b6c3789f67afe5a4c6140d",
                "category_option": [
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "en": "bb",
                            "ar": "الخبرة الشاملة"
                        },
                        "optional": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "sequence": 0,
                        "draggable": true,
                        "is_deleted": true,
                        "updated_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
                        "deleted_by": null,
                        "_id": "63b6ce9674af1e81317ef2ff"
                    }
                ],
                "name": {
                    "en": "Please rate the following items c",
                    "ar": "يرجى تقييم العناصر التالية"
                },
                "sequence": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

i want to apply sort here and want to filter data by is_deleted. if is_deleted:true then i want data for particular question and particular category_question but whenever i run $map query it is returning me Boolean value.

code i have written:

```
const getSurvey = await SurveyQuestions.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          brand_id: brand_id,
          experience_type_id: experience_type,
          is_deleted: FALSE,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          question: {
            $map: {
              input: "$question",
              as: "q",
              in: {
                $eq: ["$$q.is_deleted", true],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
)]
```

i am getting result as belove,

```
{
        "_id": "63b6c24fa14b7a7762f053f5",
        "question": [
            true,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false
        ],
        "brand_id": "63b6bccbbc400713acba8fbe",
        "experience_type_id": "63b6c24fa14b7a7762f053f3",
        "is_disable": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "created_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
        "updated_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
        "deleted_by": null,
        "createdAt": "2023-01-05T12:27:59.741Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-01-06T04:25:41.547Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

desired result should be =>

```
 {
    "_id": "63b6c24fa14b7a7762f053f5",
    "question": [
        {
            "type": "single",
            "optional": false,
            "options": null,
            "is_disable": false,
            "is_deleted": true,
            "draggable": false,
            "choice": null,
            "updated_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
            "deleted_by": null,
            "_id": "63b6c3789f67afe5a4c6140d",
            "category_option": [
                {
                    "name": {
                        "en": "bb",
                        "ar": "الخبرة الشاملة"
                    },
                    "optional": false,
                    "editable": false,
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "draggable": true,
                    "is_deleted": true,
                    "updated_by": "6360e17547fbf84e159a3777",
                    "deleted_by": null,
                    "_id": "63b6ce9674af1e81317ef2ff"
                }
            ],
            "name": {
                "en": "Please rate the following items c",
                "ar": "يرجى تقييم العناصر التالية"
            },
            "sequence": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample documents and requested results that match each other

Comment: it seems you want to use `$filter` instead of `$map`

Comment: but i want to filter that data inside category_option also so maybe i need to first map the question array and then apply filter on that i am not sure if you can help me let me share mongo playground. https://mongoplayground.net/p/iWxAd2V3R5M here instead of true i need object which is matching condition so i can apply another filter query on q.category_option.is_deleted

Comment: You can filter both. Your example does not contain items to keep and items to drop, you only have one item in each array...